# Solve for positive real solutions of cyclic equations $x+y^2+2xy=9$, $y+z^2+2yz=47$, $z+x^2+2xz=16$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> Solve over positive reals $$x+y^2+2xy=9$$
>   $$y+z^2+2yz=47$$
>   $$z+x^2+2xz=16$$

With standard manipulation we get that $x+y+z=8$. Thus $x=8-y-z$ and we have two equations,
$$(8-y-z)^2+y^2+2(8-y-z)y=9$$
$$y+z^2+2yz=47$$
Which becomes
$$-y^2-2yz+15y-z=1$$
$$y+z^2+2yz=47$$
Adding up gets
$$-y^2+16y+z^2-z=1$$
$$\implies z^2=z+1+y^2-16y$$
And this substitutes to 
$$y+z+1+y^2-16y+2yz=47$$
$$\implies y+\bigg(\frac{-y^2+15y-1}{2y+1}\bigg)+1+y^2-16y+2y\bigg(\frac{-y^2+15y-1}{2y+1}\bigg)=47$$
However, this results into a nasty quartic which I don't know how to simplify. Thanks!

Comment: You can get $x+y+z=8$ by summing up all three equations, which gives $(x+y+z)(x+y+z+1) = 72$.

Comment: Also, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%2B%5Cbigg%28%5Cfrac%7B-y%5E2%2B15y-1%7D%7B2y%2B1%7D%5Cbigg%29%2B1%2By%5E2-16y%2B2y%5Cbigg%28%5Cfrac%7B-y%5E2%2B15y-1%7D%7B2y%2B1%7D%5Cbigg%29%3D47) says that your quartic has no solutions in $y$ because you get $0=47$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continue by substituting $z=\frac{-y^2+15y-1}{2y+1}$ into $y+z^2+2yz=47$,

$$y+\left(\frac{-y^2+15y-1}{2y+1}\right)^2+2y\left(\frac{-y^2+15y-1}{2y+1}\right)=47$$

Simplify,

$$-3y^4+32y^3+69y^2-219y-46=0$$

and factorize

$$(y-2)(3y^3-26y^2-121y-23)=0$$

which yields the positive real solutions $x=1,\>y=2,\>z=5$. The other three sets of solutions are also real, but containing negative values.

Comment: How can I prove those other solutions are negative without resorting to the cubic formula?

Comment: @Baker013273213 - you may apply the Descartes' rule of signs.

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{cases}
x+y^2+2xy=9\\
y+z^2+2yz=47\\
z+x^2+2xz=16
\end{cases} \implies
\begin{cases}
(2 x + 2 y)^2 - (2 x - 1)^2 = 35\\
(2 y + 2 z)^2 - (2 y - 1)^2 = 187\\
(2 z + 2 x)^2 - (2 z - 1)^2 = 63
\end{cases} \implies
\begin{cases}
x=1\\
y=2\\
z=5
\end{cases}$

Comment: Could you elaborate on your steps a little more?

Comment: It's $\text{Eqn} \times 4 - 1$